# I want to get .dat and .ctl file extensions from a folder using VB

Tags: vb.net

I want to get .dat and .ctl file extensions from a folder and put it in a 2-dimensional array or something. Then display the two different file extensions under two different columns in the body of an email. How to do it.

Thanx SysDragon, but how do i get the files name in the rows of the table dynamically. I have to display a table format in the body of the mail with one column containing the datfiles and the other ctl files. How do i fill the rows. My code so far is:

```
Dim str As New StringBuilder
            str.Append("<html><head></head><title></title>")
            str.Append("<body style='font-size:12px;font-family:Trebuchet MS;'>")
            str.Append("<table width='600px' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-top:5px solid white;'")
            str.Append("<tr><td>DATFiles</td><td>CTLFiles</td></tr><tr><td>  datfiles  </td><td> ctlfiles </td> </tr></tr></table>")
```

The datfiles and ctlfiles should be the names of the files present in the particular folder.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  If you are having trouble with all of it, take it one step at a time, asking separate questions along the way.  As @DanielA.White has said, please show what you have tried and explain what about it didn't work.

Comment: Actually previously i was working with only dat files but now i have to display clt file extension as well. How do i get the two different file extension from the same folder and display it in different columns.

Comment: @user2281731 please post some code.

Comment: Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("Y:\~", "*.dat", "*.ctl")

 For Each file In files
         Console.WriteLine(file)

I can't understand as to how do i get both the file extension in a List.

Comment: Edit your question (instead of writing comments) giving all the information need for us to answer. Better questions make better answers. Please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the file list in two different array, then loop through the arrays to generate the html.

```
Dim datFiles As String() = Directory.GetFiles("Y:\~", ".dat")
Dim ctlFiles As String() = Directory.GetFiles("Y:\~", ".ctl")

Dim index As Integer = 0

While index < datFiles.Count Or index < ctlFiles.Count
    str.Append("<tr>")
    str.Append("<td>" & datFiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index) & "</td>")
    str.Append("<td>" & ctlFiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index) & "</td>")
    str.Append("</tr>")

    index += 1
End While
```

Comment: Thanx alot the_lotus for ur help.

Comment: @the_lotus..This is fine but how do i get/pass the list of files in email

Comment: If you want to send an email, you'll have to use System.Net.Mail. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can get the files you want (specifiying extension, for example) from a directory with these:

- [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx)
- [FyleSystem.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127994.aspx)

Take a look at the MSDN Documentation in the links given. They have examples as well.

---

Once you have the arrays with the files, you want to put the data on columns inside the email. You can do it with HTML (with a table, for example) in your body email or with plain text using tab chars.

To make your body email use HTML code, using:

```
Dim mail As New Net.Mail.MailMessage()
mail.IsBodyHTML = True
```

And then use the tags you want:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>File DAT 1</td>
        <td>File CTL 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>File DAT 2</td>
        <td>File CTL 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You have to add this as a text to your HTML body, using a loop for the array of the files.

---

To fill the table with data with a loop, a simple example:

```
Dim sBodyTable As String = "<table>"
Dim iMaxIndex As Integer = IIf(datFiles.Length > ctlFiles.Length, datFiles.Length, ctlFiles.Length)

For i As Integer = 0 To iMaxIndex - 1
    sBodyTable &= "<tr><td>"
    sBodyTable &= IIf(i < datFiles.Length, datFiles(i), "")
    sBodyTable &= "</td><td>"
    sBodyTable &= IIf(i < ctlFiles.Length, ctlFiles(i), "")
    sBodyTable &= "</td></tr>"
Next

sBodyTable &= "</table>"
```

Comment: Thanx SysDragon. Please tell me how do i add names of the files dynamically in the mail. Check my question for the code.

Comment: Do you want us to do all the work? And there should be different questions. Read carefully the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Anyway, I edit to give you your answer.

Comment: Thank u once again...SysDragon

Comment: Is there a way to pass the list/array of dat & ctl files in the email and then display them in mail body

Comment: Of course it is but I wasted too many time on you on what would be a lot of different questions and got nothing from you. No points no answer marked as correct so create a new specific question about your new problem.