# Need to get a list of 2 different file types from a folder and display it in the body of an email in tab le format

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have to get a list of 2 different file types from a folder and display it in the body of an email in table format. My code is:

```
Dim dat_files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\~", "*.dat")
            Dim ctl_files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\~", "*.ctl")

            For Each ctlfiles In ctl_files
                For Each datfiles In dat_files
                    Email(datfiles, ctlfiles)
                Next

            Next
```

And the code for email is:

```
Public Shared Sub Email(ByVal datfiles, ByVal ctlfiles)
```

'some code

```
 Dim str As New StringBuilder

            Dim index As Integer = 0

            While index < datfiles.Count Or index < ctlfiles.Count
                str.Append("<tr>")
                str.Append("<td>" & datfiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index) & "</td>")
                str.Append("<td>" & ctlfiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index) & "</td>")
                str.Append("</tr>")

                index += 1
            End While
            objMail.Body = sb.ToString
```

### This is not working. The problem is am not getting all the dat & ctl files in the mail thus cannot display them in two different columns. I know am asking too much but can anyone please help.

These are the changes i made-

```
Dim dat_files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\~", "*.dat")
            Dim ctl_files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\~", "*.ctl")
            Email(dat_files, ctl_files)
```

And the email part is-

```
 Public Shared Sub Email(ByVal datfiles As String(), ByVal ctlfiles As String())

Dim sb As New StringBuilder

            Dim index As Integer = 0

            While index < datfiles.Count Or index < ctlfiles.Count
                sb.Append("<tr>")
                sb.Append("<td>" & datfiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index) & "</td>")
                sb.Append("<td>" & ctlfiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index) & "</td>")
                sb.Append("</tr>")

                index += 1
            End While
            objMail.Body = sb.ToString
```

The error- 'Count' is not a member of 'System.Array' shows wherever count or ElementAtOrDefault is used

Comment: Could you show the actual dat and ctl files?

Comment: It doesn't matter what files those are. I just want their names to be displayed in mail. And it can can be some text files also so it doesn't matter.

Comment: seems like you construct and assign the email body for every files found in the folder, overwriting the previous construct. Check your line: `objMail.Body = sb.ToString` in your `Email(ByVal datfiles, ByVal ctlfiles)` sub; and `Email(datfiles, ctlfiles)` inside `For Each datfiles In dat_files` loop.

Comment: On second thought, I think your code does not work at all if what you are trying to do is to generate a table of 2 columns, where all ctl files in a column, and dat files in another column, and both types are not necessarily equal in number of files.

Comment: @ajakblackgoat my thought exactly on the possible unequal number of files.

Comment: Actually the no of files is always equal so thats nothing to worry about

Comment: @ajakblackgoat I did corrections on those lines: objMail.Body = sb.ToString. But still am not getting as how to display the table

Comment: @user2281731 it looks like your edited code is ok. I use it with my own code and it works just fine, honestly.

Comment: @Thirdy The error shows when i write as such- Public Shared Sub Email(ByVal datfiles As String(), ByVal ctlfiles As String()).  But no error shows when i remove the 'As String()' part from this line. But doing both its not working. There is an exception in the email part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to get .dat and .ctl file extensions from a folder using VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297920/i-want-to-get-dat-and-ctl-file-extensions-from-a-folder-using-vb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not?

In Your Main

```
        Dim dat_files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\~", "*.dat")
        Dim ctl_files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\~", "*.ctl")

        Email(dat_files, ctl_files)
```

And the Email method itself

```
       Public Shared Sub Email(ByVal datfiles as String(), ByVal ctlfiles as String())

       Dim str As New StringBuilder

       Dim index As Integer = 0

       While index < datfiles.Count Or index < ctlfiles.Count
            str.Append("<tr>")
            str.Append("<td>" & datfiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index) & "</td>")
            str.Append("<td>" & ctlfiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index) & "</td>")
            str.Append("</tr>")

            index += 1
        End While
        objMail.Body = sb.ToString()

      End Sub
```

You are passing a String

```
  Email(datfiles, ctlfiles)
```

And then inside the Email method you treat the datfile as an array of String when in fact you pass it as a simple String

```
  While index < datfiles.Count Or index < ctlfiles.Count
```

The .Count method is for *String()* not for *String*

**This is the Solution if you're using Visual Studio 2008 and up.**

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

  Sub Main()

    Dim dat_files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\test\", "*.dat")
    Dim ctl_files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\test\", "*.ctl")
    Email(dat_files, ctl_files)

  End Sub


  Public Sub Email(ByVal datfiles As String(), ByVal ctlfiles As String())

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    Dim index As Integer = 0

    While index < datfiles.Count Or index < ctlfiles.Count
        sb.Append("<tr>")
        sb.Append("<td>" & Path.GetFileName(datfiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index)) & "</td>")
        sb.Append("<td>" & Path.GetFileName(ctlfiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index)) & "</td>")
        sb.Append("</tr>")

        index += 1
    End While
    'objMail.Body = sb.ToString
    Debug.Print(sb.ToString())
  End Sub
End Module
```

**This is the Solution if you're using Visual Studio 2005 and lower:**

It uses Length instead of **Count** and
It uses the simple index like **datfiles(index)** instead of ElementAtOrDefault() like datfiles.ElementAtOrDefault(index)

Imports System.IO

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()

    Dim dat_files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\test\", "*.dat")
    Dim ctl_files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\test\", "*.ctl")
    Email(dat_files, ctl_files)

  End Sub


  Public Sub Email(ByVal datfiles As String(), ByVal ctlfiles As String())

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    Dim index As Integer = 0

    While index < datfiles.Length Or index < ctlfiles.Length
        sb.Append("<tr>")
        sb.Append("<td>" & Path.GetFileName(datfiles(index)) & "</td>")
        sb.Append("<td>" & Path.GetFileName(ctlfiles(index)) & "</td>")
        sb.Append("</tr>")

        index += 1
    End While
    'objMail.Body = sb.ToString
    Debug.Print(sb.ToString())
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: @Thirdy..Its working like a charm...Thanx....Sorry to bother u again but when i get the table, the last row is separated from the other rows by many lines. Why is it displaying in such a manner?

Comment: Try to debug it and check why is the last value or as you've said the last row is like that. It's a little bit difficult to guess if do not see the actual output. In my case i don't have that kind of problem. So, maybe it could be your .dat or .ctl files has/have extra lines that are not needed or it could be something else.

Comment: @Thirdy...Got it. It was just some allignment problem in the table.